# How can I dynamically associate a TextBlock with a Grid's Column?

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, grid

I want to dynamically create a 1-row grid and add some TextBlocks to it, assigning/associating each one to a different column in the grid. I've got this code:

```
SolidColorBrush samHagar = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
System.Windows.Thickness mrg = new Thickness(2);

// Create a Grid
Grid grd = new Grid();
. . . // TODO: add columns
//...add the Grid to the StackPanel
spNufan.Children.Add(grd);

// Create TextBlock and dynamically add it  to the Grid
TextBlock tbDynamo = new TextBlock();
tbDynamo.Background = samHagar;
tbDynamo.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
//tbDynamo.Grid.Column = 0; <- no go, Joe!
tbDynamo.Margin = mrg;
tbDynamo.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
tbDynamo.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
tbDynamo.Text = "Whatever";
spNufan.Children.Add(grd);
```

How can I affiliate my TextBlock ("tbDynamo") with my Grid ("grd")?

Comment: I assume "to a different _row_ in the grid" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the object's `Grid.Column` property, then add the object to the Grid

```
Grid.SetColumn(tbDynamo, 0);
grd.Children.Add(tbDynamo);
```

As a side note, you don't actually need to set it to 0 since items in a `Grid` will default to `Grid.Row=0` and `Grid.Column=0` unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Why does everybody wants to set the _Column_ to its default value?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Because that is what the OP asked for. I upvoted your comment btw because a 1-column Grid doesn't actually need to have `Grid.Column` set

Comment: This grid has 8 columns; I just didn't show the column creationg code in my listing.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like

```
// untested    
// spNufan.Children.Add(grd);  // already done earlier
grd.Children.Add(tbDynamo);
Grid.SetRow(tbDynamo, i);
```

But I would seriously look into StackPanel and ListBox first. They seem more appropriate than a Grid.
How do you want scrolling to look?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Grid.SetColumn(tbDynamo, 0);`